# Ubuntuで充電すると明るさが最低になる件について

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Let's Note SZ6にUbuntu 18.04.3 LTSを入れて使用しており、充電するとディスプレイの明るさが最低になります。その度Fn+F1で明るさを調節しているのですが、原因としては何が考えれますでしょうか？

ターミナルで設定をいじって解決できれば良いのですが、インストールに使ったLive USBが悪かったのか、わかりません。

Comment: 古い機種や古い情報で関連不明なので参考にはならないかも。[Let’sNoteにUbuntu17.10インストール](https://gtrt7.com/blog/linux/ubuntu1710-on-letsnote), [Let's Note CF-SZ6 に Debian GNU/Linux をインストール・環境設定](https://qiita.com/tsuchm/items/1b28d1bb7714e3847ac1), [Let's note SZ で Ubuntu](http://iranoan.my.coocan.jp/essay/pc/201609061.htm), [レッツノートCF-RZ5にLinuxMintを入れて、無線LANが使えるようにする](https://akiba-neo.com/letsnote/rz5/397/), [Let's note に Linux Mintをインストールする](https://blue-red.ddo.jp/~ao/wiki/wiki.cgi?page=Let%27s+note+%A4%CB+Linux+Mint%A4%F2%A5%A4%A5%F3%A5%B9%A5%C8%A1%BC%A5%EB%A4%B9%A4%EB)

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかし変わりませんでした....

Comment: そのとおりにやってみたものの、:wq で書き込み終了しようとしてもe212: can't open file for writingと出てきて終了できないんですよね...

Comment: そのエラーは権限がない時以外にディレクトリがないときにも出るようなので`/etc/pm/power.d/` 自体は存在しますか？

Comment: ディレクトリを移動してみると'/etc/pm/'まではありましたが、pmの中にpower.dはありませんでした

Comment: 初歩的な問題で、ディレクトリがなかったので作って　https://askubuntu.com/a/292514　を参考にそのまま書き込むと問題なく書き込み終了できたのですが、結局明るさが勝手に最低になる問題は解決しませんでした。

Answer (score 2):

なぜ暗くなるかは定かではありませんが、ACPIでAC電源のイベントを検知して、明るさ調整することはできるかもしれません。

前提条件として、`/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` で輝度が変更できる必要があります。
機種ごとにパスが異なるので事前に確認してください。

```
# ls -1 /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
# cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
937  ←現在の輝度設定
# cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness
937  ←設定可能な最大値
# echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  ←輝度100（暗い）
# echo 500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  ←輝度500（明るい）
# echo 937 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness  ←最大輝度
```

AC電源を付けた時のイベントを確認します。
acpi_listen を実行して、その状態でAC電源を取り付けてください。

```
$ acpi_listen
ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000   ← AC電源を外した時に出力されたイベント
（略）
ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000001   ← AC電源を取り付けた時に出力されたイベント
（略）
```

ACPIイベントの設定ファイルを作成します。
例：/etc/acpi/events/ac-pluged

```
event=ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000001  ←先ほど確認したイベント
action=/etc/acpi/ac-pluged.sh  ←イベント検知した際に実行するコマンド
```

アクションで実行するスクリプトを作成します。
例：/etc/acpi/ac-pluged.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
KEYS_DIR=/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
test -d $KEYS_DIR || exit 0
# 輝度を最大（max_brightness）に設定
VAL=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/max_brightness)
echo $VAL > $KEYS_DIR/brightness
```

KEYS_DIRの値は、最初に確認したディレクトリを指定してください。

acpid を restart すれば反映されます。

```
# systemctl restart acpid
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そっくりやってみたものの変わりませんでした...

Comment: それは残念でした。何かしらの電源管理のシステムが動いていると思うので、ご自身のパソコンの中身を調べてみるといいかも。電源周りはハードに依存する部分も多いので、ネットで同じ機種の情報を探してみるのもいいかもしれません。